# COUNT with SELECT by IF condition

Tags: sql

I was looking for count of two sql queries if they're truly equal

```
SELECT c.name,
count ( IF (

            (SELECT count(*) FROM catey_content cm WHERE cm.sid = c.id AND cm.state = 1) 
             =      

            (SELECT count(*) FROM catey_content_comp cmc WHERE cm.sid = c.id AND cmc.state BETWEEN 1 
             AND 10)    
            )
       ) AS "completed"

FROM category_it c GROUP BY c.name
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: There is no `IF` in "SQL" (SQL is a query language, not the name of a specific database product - [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/))

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your non-working query doesn't fully explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want check some condition you could use the where  clause 
and also use join on subquery

```
     SELECT c.name, "completed"
     FROM category_it c 
     INNER JOIN  (
         SELECT sid, count(*) count_cm
         FROM catey_content cm WHERE cm.state = 1
         GROUP BY sid
    ) t1 on t1.sid = c.id
    INNER JOJN (
     SELECT sid, count(*) count_cmc
     FROM catey_content_comp cmc 
     WHERE  cmc.state  BETWEEN 1  AND 10
     GROUP BY sid
    ) t2 on t2.sid = c.id
    WHERE t1.count_cm = t2.count_cmc
```

Comment: SELECT c.name,  ...FROM category_it c  is from your code  ..  anyway answer  updated  (wrongly missing an inner group by)

Comment: which db you are using  ???  .. anyway in SQL the INNER JOIN comes after the FROM table

Comment: Edge : It was working now. Many Thanks for the support.